# Making fake DataFrame/TimeDataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Just found out that `pandas.util.testing.makeDataFrame` no longer exists.

Where is it moved to? Or if it is completely gone, is there a substitute for easy testing functionality?

Comment: It's available under `pandas._testing.makeDataFrame`